# Can jquery $.when() and $.then() return jquery Deferred without creating Deferred object explicitly?

Tags: jquery

Below jquery code segment works perfectly but an explicate
`$.Deferred()` is created inside myFunction(). Is it possible to avoid this explicate `$.Deferred()` creation? Is it follow antipattern?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.when(
         myFunction()
      )
     .then(function (result) {
             //Do rest of the work
      })
});    

function myFunction() {
     var deferred = $.Deferred();
     $.when(
            someOtherAction()
     )
     .then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result)
     })

     return deferred.promise();
}

function someOtherAction()
{
     //Long running work...., returns either true or false after            
     //execution

     return true;
}
```

Comment: You can declare your deferred inside .ready and pass it through

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to create $.Deferred(), just searching an option if explicate Deferred object creation can be avoided. Is there any inbuilt feature available for $.when()/$.then()?

Comment: It depends what is doing someOtherAction method?!

Comment: only other jQuery way to create deferred object is with `$.ajax` or any of it's shorthand methods

Comment: if `Long running work` returns a boolean, what do you need a promise for? it's all synchronous. that or the boolean is actually returned before, not *"after"*.

Comment: @charlietfl you can use promise on queue too, like when using the animate method

Comment: Thanks! Explicitly checking whether $.when()/$.then() can return promise or not. It can.

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) and you're done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return a Promise object from `myFunction` instead of a Deferred object and things will work as you expect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.when(myFunction())
    .done(function(result) {
      // ...
      console.log("all done");
    }).fail(function(err) {
      // ...
    });
});

function myFunction() {
  return ($.when(someOtherAction())
            .done(function(result) {
              return (result);
            }).fail(function(err) {
              // ...
            })
         );
}

function someOtherAction() {
  // ...
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { ; }
  return (true);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vt7825v/)

Comment: Do not use `done`/`fail`! You cannot `return` from them - you want `then`!

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note... you don't need to use `$.when` when you only have *one* promise.  You can just do:

```
myFunction().then(function(result){}
});
```

That being said, you need to create a `$.Deferred` object *somewhere* in order to return a promise.  Some jQuery methods return you a promise already, like `$.ajax` (because they create a new `$.Deferred` internally).

Why not have `someOtherAction()` return a promise instead of a boolean?  You can have it call `deferred.resolve` with the boolean (and/or any other variables you need).  I don't think you really need `myFunction()`.

Comment: No, a function that can return synchronously should do so, and not create a promise for you. If you want to wrap a value in a promise (for whatever reason), just use `$.when`

Comment: @Bergi: That's not quite how `$.when` works.  `$.when` basically *combine* multiple promises into one.  If the method is *synchronous*, then you don't need promises at all!

Comment: @Bergi: If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Yes, if the method is synchronous, you don't need promises at all, so please don't suggest to return a promise instead of a boolean. But if you still want to do, you can just use `return $.when(true)` without needing to construct a deferred manually.